# Current url into cookie file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, url, cookies

Short question is : "How do I save current url into cookie file?"

And the whole problem is as follows. I have to save current filters that client have applied to my grid in his cookie, that next time he logs in the data looks just as he wants it to look like. The service doesn't have any "login" stuff, just provides available data to the user. This whole thing is written in ASP.MVC/C#.

If you have any other solutions to this task I will be happy to discuss them!

Thanks for giving a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

In short, you can access the user's cookie data by calling Response.Cookies to get a dictionary of HttpCookie objects keyed by the name you give each cookie (much like Session or ViewState data stores). You can add to this by specifying a cookie name in the indexer as if it were there and setting Value and ExpirationDate properties, or by creating a new HttpCookie and calling Cookies.Add.

It may not be necessary to store the whole URL, although a cookie can contain up to 4k of data. I would instead store the query string (which has the pertinent filter settings) under a unique name that that specific page will know to get its cookie data from ("`<page name here>FilterSettings`", perhaps). Then, on PreInit, get the Request, and if its QueryString is empty but there's a Cookie with saved filter settings, tack the saved query string onto the current url and redirect.

Remember that the client has control over whether to save cookie data; the browser may accept all, accept from trusted sources, ask on all, or refuse all. In this case, no big deal; it's pure convenience, which is exactly what a cookie should be used for. If this were valuable data, you may have had to persist it server-side based on the user.

Comment: Well that's what I was looking for. Thank's a lot! This is more then enough for my app. I'm usually trying not to save any data at the client side. But this time it's the only way to persist data. Thank's a lot again!

Comment: Why do you have to get the cookie data in the preinit and not on the page_onload event?

Comment: It doesn't have to be OnPreInit, but that's the earliest handle-able event in the ASP lifecycle. No use in having IIS go through the initialization phase when you can know before you start that you will just be starting over again with the query string.